# python マストドンのトレンドキーワードを取得する。

Tags: python, python3, mastodon

マストドンでトレンドになっているキーワードもしくはハッシュタグを取得したいと思います。
ググってみましたが、そのような情報は見つかりませんでした。
twitterのAPIではトレンドを取得する方法がありましたが、マストドンにもあるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2018 年 9 月現在、Mastodon の [API ドキュメント](https://github.com/tootsuite/documentation/blob/master/Using-the-API/API.md)にはトレンド (trend) 用の機能が書かれていません。

そもそも Mastodon のトレンド機能自体が [Pull Request #7711](https://github.com/tootsuite/mastodon/pull/7711) (2018年6月) で削除されています。Mastodon ドキュメントのリポジトリ内において "trend" で検索したところ、過去にはトレンド用の API が[あった](https://github.com/tootsuite/documentation/commit/8c4a7413b9f27f1d9b7899a8232e163ddb247c09)ものの、やはり[削除されています](https://github.com/tootsuite/documentation/commit/4f1e930508362b2b93752d4f2cb2553af3f71127)。

この変更に追従していない fork であればまだこの機能があるかもしれませんが、その場合はまずそのトレンドが独自実装のものなのか本家のものなのか確認する必要があります。後者の場合、更新と共に削除される可能性があるのでご注意ください。

Comment: twitter API を踏襲しているといわれていたので、あるのかだろうかと思っていたのですが、無念です。